# python scipy FFT can't plot, and result does not looks good by my dataset

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, fft

I am trying to use scipy.fft to see the noise in my data.
The raw data is a electrical signal dataset which collect by oscilloscope.

The primary frequency is 60MHz,
The total is 250000 data points(rows) which is 2 sec(in reality).
The noise should be all over the place.

The problem is that when I plot it, the xf and yf can't aligned.

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (270000000,) and (250000,)

I copied the code from:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/fft.html

It doesn't work well for my dataset, but I am not sure why this happened.
My dataset is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19HFOIZyfI0rOy2_G-csqtCs7He27LhLg/view?usp=sharing

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fft import fft, fftfreq

df = pandas.read_csv("Stephan0314_V8CHH2F_ME1.csv", skiprows=20)

SAMPLE_RATE = 180000000         #Hz
DURATION = int((df["TIME"].max() - df["TIME"].min()) * 1000) #ms

N = SAMPLE_RATE * DURATION

x = df['CH2'].to_numpy()

yf = fft(x)
xf = fftfreq(N, 1 / SAMPLE_RATE)[:N//2]

plt.plot(xf, 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[0:N//2]))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SAMPLE_RATE is incorrect.

If 250,000 rows amount to 2s, your SAMPLE_RATE should be 125kHz, yet you specify `SAMPLE_RATE = 180000000`.

Correcting the SAMPLE_RATE yields the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I think I made a mistake in the description. In reality, the data was in 0.004 sec, so I set `SAMPLERATE=62500000` base on the the method you provided. I got my primary frequency is about 2MHz which is close to the 60MHz.